# Run a executable file on Android.

Tags: android

I would like to use:
http://newandroidbook.com/tools/jtrace.html

To do it, I started avd emulator based on x86-64 CPU. Now, I do:

```
adb push jtrace.x86 /data/local/tmp
adb shell
cd /data/local/tmp
./jtrace.x86
```

And, as a result, I've got an error: 
`/system/bin/sh: ./jtrace.x86: No such file or directory`

However, the file exists in fact.

How to solve it?